# mongoid .limit does not work in mongoid 3.1.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

i tried something like this in rails with mongoid 3.1.0 and lastest 3.1.3.
.limit does not work. below it should return 1 row but it returns all (4)

code:

```
@go = Gallery.limit(1)
logger.info "count: #{@go.count}"
```

output:

```
 count: 4
 MOPED: 54.234.11.193:10055 QUERY database=mongohqtestdatabase collection=galleries selector=  {"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (276.2010
```

ms)

which version of mongoid is good with limit() ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `limit` command works fine, but for some reason `count` ignores the limit.  If you cast it to an array you'll see that the limit is working.

```
Array(Gallery.limit(1)).length  # this gives 1
```

Also, if you actually iterate through the objects you'll see that the limit is working.

Comment: It's polite to upvote an answer if you found it useful, and accept it if it answers your question.

Comment: This is not a good idea as it will load all the documents into memory, the solution for Mongoid 5 below is far superior!

Answer (score 18):

As suggested in the official [Mongoid answer](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-2981), we should be using `Gallery.limit(1).count(true)`

Comment: @Dean your link is dead

Comment: @Geoffroy Fixed the link!

Answer (score 4):

For Mongoid 5 the parameter of `CollectionView#count` changed :

```
    # Get a count of matching documents in the collection.
    #
    # @example Get the number of documents in the collection.
    #   collection_view.count
    #
    # @param [ Hash ] options Options for the count command.
    #
    # @option options :skip [ Integer ] The number of documents to skip.
    # @option options :hint [ Hash ] Override default index selection and force
    #   MongoDB to use a specific index for the query.
    # @option options :limit [ Integer ] Max number of docs to return.
    # @option options :max_time_ms [ Integer ] The maximum amount of time to allow the
    #   command to run.
    #
    # @return [ Integer ] The document count.
    #
    # @since 2.0.0
```

So you can do something like

```
collection.count(limit: 1) # => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the document id's. Make an array of them, create a query that searches only those document id's and updates them together.

```
ids = Model.where(foo: 'bar').only('_id').limit(1000).to_a
Model.where(:_id.in => ids).update_all(foo: 'baz')
```