# Get a limited set of results in sub collection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm trying to get a limited set of results in a sub collection

Basically I have this:

```
user = Model::User.find(token)
playlists = user.playlists
playlists.each do |playlist|
  criteria = playlist.tracks.limit(4)    #I Want to limit these to return max 4 tracks
  #the criteria is perfect here but the decorator still returns all the tracks
  #setting this criteria on the user saves the new tracks list limited by 4
  #like this:
  playlists[index].tracks = criteria
end

decorator = Decorator::PlaylistCollection.new(playlist)
response_with decorator
```

This isn't working, and my question is how can I limit every playlist to return 4 tracks max

What I want is that the response contains all the playlists with 4 tracks max in it (also the queries on mongo should be optimized)

- display all the playlist
- every playlist contains max 4 tracks
- it's required to prevent the call for all the tracks of the playlist from mongoid/mongo

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do exactly in the `each` block? You're not saving the n first records anywhere.

Comment: No this code isn't working, i want to build the response with the decorator with 4 tracks for each playlist

Comment: Have a look here, this seems like a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074404/mongoid-limit-does-not-work-in-mongoid-3-1-x

Comment: No it's not, i don't want to count how many results the criteria has returned. (count returns all the tracks in playlist and ignores the limit). that isn't my issue

Comment: I have it working, i will post an answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, mongoid creates an array with ids (track_ids) with all the ids of the tracks in the list.

By overriding the track_ids instead of  tracks nothing is queried or stored in mongoid.

```
user = Model::User.find(token)
playlists = user.playlists
playlists.map do |playlist|
  playlist.track_ids = playlist.track_ids.take(4)
end

decorator = Decorator::PlaylistCollection.new(playlist)
response_with decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following code would do the trick.

```
user = Model::User.find(token)
playlists = user.playlists[0..3]
decorator = Decorator::PlaylistCollection.new(playlist)
response_with decorator
```

Comment: You get the first 3 playlists, what i wanted was the get all the playlists but just 4 tracks for every playlist instead all tracks